# Classic Haunted Mansion Game

Tags: identify-this-game

I am trying to remember the name of a old haunted mansion game I played.  I remember you started in the Foyer and built the mansion as you explored out of mansion tiles.  The tiles were unique because they were elevated to have several different heights.  You were looking for chests/treasure with gold in them.  Once you found them you had to escape the mansion.

I thought it was just called Haunted Mansion but that doesn't seem to be it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mystery Mansion?

http://boardgamegeek.com/image/586882/mystery-mansion

I remember playing this game. Interesting idea.

Answer (score 2):

I used to play [Betrayal at House on the Hill](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/10547/betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill) but I think this game is newer than what you are thinking. This came out in 2004.

What you're describing sounds more like [Haunted House](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/12867/haunted-house) Which came out in 1962

Do you remember what year(s) you played it?

Comment: That wasn't it (closer to Haunted House though), I played it around the 80s but not sure how old it was then.